# Is there a way to find which capacity has not enough capacity in network_simplex by networkx?

Tags: network-programming, networkx, spyder, linear-programming

I am working with the network_simplex algorithm in networkx to analyse a model of the HV-grid in the Netherlands. It consists of 106 lines and 31 nodes. If I run network_simplex it returns a lists of the lines and their flows, or it gives the error:

> NetworkXUnfeasible: no flow satisfies all node demands.

This is because the capacity of the lines are not enough to fulfill the demands of the nodes. I have to look what the problem is in the network_simplex algorithm and which capacity of what line should be higher and how high it should be, however the network_simplex algorithm does not give such an indication. The problem is that I can not increase all the capacities because then the capacity-restriction is not there anymore. Does anyone have ideas how to solve where it goes wrong and how to make an algorithm to higher this capacity?

The source code says this:

```html
if any(x[i] != 0 for i in range(-n, 0)):
        raise nx.NetworkXUnfeasible('no flow satisfies all node demands')
```

Comment: My capacities of my lines are in my excel file in where I have a column from node a to node b and then a column with capacities

Comment: My normal approach would be to look at which capacities are binding. Unfortunately, this function does not return duals and reduced costs.

Comment: Could you give an example? I don't think I understand. I need to find the restraints of capacities of the lines which are not met with Network_Simplex. I saw that there is a way to do this with constraint relaxation algorithms, but I can not find an algorithm or package on the internet.

Comment: The simplex method returns information that shows which constraints are which bounds are binding. These are good candidates to relax to improve the objective. Any LP (or network solver) I know of returns marginal: duals for constraints and reduced costs for variables with this information. See any book on linear programming. Unfortunately, this particular routine does not return this information.